# No matching client found for package name "...." with different buildvariant

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, kotlin

I want to implement push notification.
I added to project level:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

and to app level:(at the bottom of the file)

```
   ....
   compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Then I added google-services.json file to project in app level

But, when I syncro gradle, it launch the error:

```
No matching client found for package name "...."
```

In gradle I have 2 different build variants , and look like:

[image]

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="es.xxx.awsomeapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name=".realm.XXXXXX"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_chv"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
```

And finally the gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven' }
    mavenCentral()
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    productFlavors {
        vanilla {
            applicationId "es.xxx.awsomeApp"
            resValue 'string', 'app_name', "Awsome"
        }
        chv {
            applicationId "es.xxx.awsomeApp.chv"
            resValue 'string', 'app_name', "Awsome CHV"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.chv_release
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //Auxiliar libraries
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.2.0-beta2'
    //Auxiliar libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.2.0-beta2'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.2.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:logger:1.15'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.Slyce-Inc:SlyceMessaging:1.1.2'
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
    testCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.2.0-beta2'
    testCompile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta2'
    testCompile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'com.orhanobut:logger:1.15'
    testCompile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'com.github.Slyce-Inc:SlyceMessaging:1.1.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And the firebase console.

[image]

How can I solve it?

Note, that json files are each one of their project.

Comment: Maybe I'm mixing some concepts? :/

Comment: Inspect the `google-services.json` files to confirm they have contain the correct package names, as described in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#processing_the_json_file).

Answer (score 41):

1. Just go to the google-services.json
2. change the package-name to the name of your package

```
{
  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:113908578702:android:a0a98decfd9f22466f4cdf",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.example.Appname"
    }
  }
}
```

3. sync your project, it'll be solved

Comment: Does this affect to analysis data?

Answer (score 38):

I was facing the same error. I am using multiple flavors. Therefore, I put the `google-services.json` in `app/src/{flv}` directory.

It worked well for one flavor but did not work for others. The issue was that I have also placed `google-services.json` corresponding to flavor for which it was working in app directory also.

**Google will search for sub-directories / flavor directories only if it did not find the `google-services.json` in the app directory.**

So, make sure you don't put `google-services.json` in app directory in case you have separate `google-services.json` for multiple flavors.

Please see [this article](https://medium.com/@droid.dev/how-to-build-multiple-apps-with-a-single-android-project-2021-android-productivity-hack-4e0b94e622b4) for mode details on Android product flavors.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit? I am having some issues with it. Did you mean that when you have a product flavour we should not add it in the app folder?

Comment: No. We should add it in app/src/your_flv directory

Comment: This is true when I use com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4. However, it didn't happen to com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3. It looks at flavors dir first.

Comment: It looks like a bug, there's nothing in the release-note. I've added details to a bug-tracker here (though its in the wrong component): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170657977

Comment: Exactly same issue, deleting from app directory worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: This is fixed with [google-services:4.3.5](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#google-services_plugin_v4-3-5)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, so using Android Studio **2.3.3** I used the menu 
**Tools**> **Firebase** - on the right side of the window click **Notifications** and then **Recieve notifications on your app**,finally click **Connect to Firebase**, after this you will see a dialog saying **This app is already connected to a project** but just click **Sync**, then firebase will sync automatically all your app clients and it will fix this issue,by the way I know it's too late to respond but it might help someone.

Comment: I had multiple build variants in my project & all had their respective google-services.json files, but somehow this issue was still showing up. So I tried connecting it using firebase tools in the android studio and that problem got resolved. Thanks!

Comment: simple yet exactly what I needed! Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

If you have added **google-service.json** file
check build.gradle(: app) **package_name** and in google-service.json file **package_name** is the same
Also if you have added **productFlavors** make sure you have added that package in firebase for creating JSON file

Answer (score 2):

Check your Gradle app level applicationId, it should be same as firebase package name, then it works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

*Go to build.gradle and change the package name with same as AndroidManifest.xml and sync again   *
[1][In this image show package name  in AndroidManifest same as  build.gradle]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4cqz.png
[Below image show package name in build.gradle same as AndroidManifest]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ModHS.png
[package name in build.gradle][2]

Also check firebase and  download recent .json file.

Answer (score 0):

Update your applicationId inside defaultConfig of app level gradle file. With your package name.

Answer (score 0):

> Try to download the latest **google-services.json** file

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit late, but maybe it could help someone like me with the same situation. I defined another app in the Firebase console at project settings with a different package name equal to my other flavor build. and then I downloaded the new google-services.json file and used it.it worked like a charm for me