# Project name and ApplicationID match but i still get this error: No matching client found for package name 'capacitor.android.plugins'

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play-services

my build.gradle(:app) has the following applicationid
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccPAC.png)

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "io.ionic.starter"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

and my google-service.json has the following package_nam:

```
"client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1xxxx",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "io.ionic.starter"
        }
    },
```

the manifest file has this package name as well:

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.ionic.starter">
```

but for some reason I keep getting this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'capacitor.android.plugins'
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587521/no-matching-client-found-for-package-name-with-different-buildvariant

Comment: try changing the app id from io.ionic.starter to com.somthing.somethingelse

Comment: For drastically improved visibility of the question, use content tag: `android`.

Comment: Try it: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/discussions/1286#discussioncomment-990011

Answer (score 2):

- add `google-services.json` file in `android/app` and `android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugin`
- edit package name in `android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugin/manifests/AndroidManifest.xml` and `android/app/build.gradle`

package should be the same as in `services.json` file.

Note -
In `build.gradle` you need to change `applicationId`.

Answer (score 0):

`io.ionic.starter` probably is the wrong one name to register on the Firebase console ...this needs to be *the actual package name*.
And the plugin obviously uses the package name of the module, where it can find  `google-services.json`.
You'd have to register the actual package name (see `ionic.config.json` or `capacitor.config.json`) and then place the new one `google-services.json` into directory `app/src/main`.

Comment: unfortunately I searched everywhere, and I wasn't able to find this "package name" nowhere. Indeed if I set my package name equals to that, I'm able to build, but off course I would not be able to push to the store. The only way I solved this issue was with a brand new ionic project.